# Get NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED from smbClient / Samba despite Linux root

Tags: linux, kvm, samba, libsmbclient

I always get the access denied error when I try to connect smbClient to my samba shared directory.

So I try to use:

> sudo smbclient "\\leon-pop-os\img_mount" -U root

I get as Expected:

> Password for [WORKGROUP\root]:

but when I login with my root password, I get:

> tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

The password is correct. I copy paste it with mouse rightclick.

In my Samba conf I already put in the GLOBAL:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
unix extensions = no
```

and my img_mount looks like this:

```
[img_mount]
comment = Windows Stuff
path = /mnt/img_mount
available = yes
writeable = yes
read only = no
valid users = root
force user = root
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
directory mask = 0775
wide links = yes
```

the img_mount directory is a mounted img from another hard disk.
I mounted it with:

> sudo mount -o rw,loop ./Windows.img /mnt/img_mount

The goal is to make it reachable in my KVM VM, I wanted to transfer all the p2v Windows files from image to my new bootable Windows 11 QCOW2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Excuse me, but did you add the root user to Samba, with 'smbpasswd -a root' ? Or tried to do this using another user, maybe that would be safer?

Answer (score -2):

Excuse me, but did you add the root user to Samba, with 'smbpasswd -a root' ? Or tried to do this using another user, maybe that would be safer?

Comment: Hi! Welcome! This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I agree. I just wanted to help, but I can't comment, the system doesn't allow it yet because I'm a new user. If you wish, you can leave a comment and I will remove the answer.